# Resultado no esperado en función PHP para abreviar una cantidad de número

Tags: php, funciones

Tengo un blog donde muestro la cantidad de visita de cada articulo que publico y algunos artículos han ganado muchas visitas y la cantidad de visitas abecés es muy larga y me arruina el responsive de la web y por eso he optado por abreviar la cantidad de visitas: p, ej. 2330 visitas = **2.3K visitas** y así de esa forma me queda mucho mejor y más bonito.

### Resultado que me lanza

Resulta que este me lanza un resultado equivocado y muy mentiroso: p, ej: 523 Visitas = **52K Visitas**
Ósea dice que son 52 mil visitas cuando en realidad son solo **523 visitas** y las que tiene por ejemplo 2,821 Visitas dice **2,8K Visitas**
Lo cual significa que hay un problema en la función que le mostrare más adelante

### Resultado que quiero

Lo que yo quiero es que si mi articulo tiene 523 Visitas, simple y llanamente diga que tienes 523 Visitas. Pero si este tiene 2,425 Visitas que este diga **2.4K** y listo.

### Función que utilizo

```
// Abreviatura de la cantidad de visitas
function abreView($visita) {
    $visitantes = number_format($visita, 0, '.', ',');
    $posicion_coma = strpos($visitantes, ",");
    return substr($visitantes, 0, ($posicion_coma + 2)) . "K";
}
```

Esta es la función que estoy utilizando para lograr mi objetivo pero tan parece algo esta mal y no se como corregirlo, espero que por favor ustedes me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes implementar esta función:

```
function number_format_short( $n, $precision = 1 ) {
    if ($n < 900) {
        // 0 - 900
        $n_format = number_format($n, $precision);
        $suffix = '';
    } else if ($n < 900000) {
        // 0.9k-850k
        $n_format = number_format($n / 1000, $precision);
        $suffix = 'K';
    } else if ($n < 900000000) {
        // 0.9m-850m
        $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000, $precision);
        $suffix = 'M';
    } else if ($n < 900000000000) {
        // 0.9b-850b
        $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000000, $precision);
        $suffix = 'B';
    } else {
        // 0.9t+
        $n_format = number_format($n / 1000000000000, $precision);
        $suffix = 'T';
    }
  // Remove unecessary zeroes after decimal. "1.0" -> "1"; "1.00" -> "1"
  // Intentionally does not affect partials, eg "1.50" -> "1.50"
    if ( $precision > 0 ) {
        $dotzero = '.' . str_repeat( '0', $precision );
        $n_format = str_replace( $dotzero, '', $n_format );
    }
    return $n_format . $suffix;
}
```

**Fuente:** [Esta respuesta de Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42358683/5587982) en la pregunta: [*Shorten long numbers to K/M/B?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4371059/5587982)

Como ves, el alcance es más largo, llegando hasta trillones... puedes quitar lo que no te interese, pero quien sabe, algún día tu sitio podría llegar a tener trillones de visitas :-).

Si estuvieras recibiendo valores con separadores de mil, puedes limpiar el dato agregando un `str_replace` al inicio de la función, así evitas problemas de números mal formateados, etc.:

```
function number_format_short( $n, $precision = 1 ) {
    $n=str_replace(array(',','.'),'',$n);
    if ($n < 900) {
        //... resto del código
}
```